# Find the kth largest integer

Tags: python

How would we pick the *kth* largest integer in an array?

```
arr = [1, 0, -34, 53, 654, 24.23, 5323, 80, 80, -11, 0, 100000]
desc = sorted(arr, reverse=True)

def kth_largest(k, arr):
    if k == 1:
        return max(arr)
    list(filter(lambda x: x != max(arr), desc)
    return desc[k]

print(kth_largest(2, arr))
```

I came across a solution on the platform but I don't think that really worked. I have tried to implement the logic I understood but I get an error running the syntax above, '''SyntaxError: invalid syntax''' on the return desc[k].

A brief explanation for the logic behind the code/explanation suggested would be much appreciated as well if possible.

Comment: just `return sorted(arr, reverse=True)[k]`

Comment: @leaf_yakitori Why use that, when I have already assigned a variable to it? Im just trying understand the concept behind your suggestion.

Comment: because it is a pythonic way to get the kth largest integer in an array.

Comment: You want to select _integers_ only. Do you distinguish by the type or value? Would you consider `2.0` to be an integer?

Comment: In this case yes, distinguish by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`k-th` largest integer, ommiting the duplicates:

```
import math

arr = [1, 0, -34, 53, 654, 24.23, 5323, 80, 80, -11, 0, 100000, 2.0, 2.0]
k_index = 4

sorted(set(x for x in arr if x-math.floor(x)==0), reverse=True)[k_index]

>> 53
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `list(filter(...))` you missed a closing parenthesis.
Your **desc** is already sorted. so a single line could have solved the problem.

```
return des[k:]
```

That will return the Kth largest elements.
If you want to return only the Kth largest single element just do.

```
return desc[k]
```

Comment: That worked! It was due to the missing parenthesis. However, if Kth=4, the answer should be 53 but it returns 80 instead. Need to skip past the duplicates, any idea how to implement the syntax for that?